# git repository clone failed. ssl peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm getting this error when I tried to clone a git repo. I take about 25 minutes and then throw a error "git repository clone failed. ssl peer shut down incorrectly"

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can this issue be reproduced with a public Git repository and if so, which steps exactly are necessary? Could you please give the exact error message including details (is there anything in the log)? Which Eclipse (or JGit/EGit) version do you use?

Comment: I went to SSH under preferences >> generals >> networks connections >> SSH to generate a RSA key encryption which I  register into my bit bucket.